# Why is my logical notation wrong? What does my answer mean then?

Tags: logic

Let `D = {all programmers and all projects}`,

`R(x) mean: "x is a programmer,"`

`T(x) mean: "x is a project,"` and

```
A(x, y) mean: "x is assigned to y."
```

For each English statement below, write a standard symbolic representation of the statement, and for
each symbolic statement, write a natural English expression of the statement.

"Some project has every programmer assigned to it."

`∃x∈D, T(x)∧ ∀y∈D, R(y) ⟹ A(y, x)` this is the solution given

`∃x∈D, T(x)∧ ∀y∈D, R(y) ∧ A(x, y)`  --> this is what I got

Why is my solution wrong?

And I noticed the flip to A(y,x) instead of A(x, y). Does the order matter?

Also!

The statement: `"No programmer is assigned to no project"`

```
¬∃x∈D, R(x) ⟹ ¬∃y∈D, T(y) ∧ A(x, y)
```

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, the order clearly matters in the statement "x is assigned to y". Your statement says that all elements in $D$ are programmers, which is clearly wrong.

Comment: Okay, if I changed the A(x, y) to A(y,x), my solution is still considered wrong. Why isn't the and symbol acceptable here?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: It is not _that_ intuitively clear that order matters here. I think you can either assign programmers to projects or projects to programmers. Being consistent is of course important.

Comment: @HenningMakholm ahh, I guess you are right.

Comment: @merlin See my answer for the other mistake ($\wedge$ instead of $\Rightarrow$)

Answer (score 2):

"Some project has every programmer assigned to it."

> $∃x∈D, T(x)∧ ∀y∈D, R(y) ∧ A(x, y)\quad$ (this is what you wrote).

What you wrote says that "there is some project x such that for all y in the domain of (all projects and all programmers), y is both a programmer and the project x is assigned to y."

That doesn't make a lot of sense, since it is asserting that all projects and programmers are programmers (and it is asserting that the existing project is assigned to all projects and programmers.)

What we want to say is "there is some project x, and for all y in the domain of (projects and programmers), if $y$ is a programmer, then $y$ is assigned to $x$. That ensures every thing that is a *programmer* in the Domain is assigned to project $x$. So the "if y is a programmer" then ... speaks only to programmers in the domain, and not to projects in the domain. And we are talking about some project $x$ *to which* all programmers y are assigned to $x$, so we need to have $A(y, x)$: programmers assigned to project, and not project assigned to programmers.

We can express this first statement correctly as follows: $$∃x∈D, \Big(T(x)∧ ∀y∈D, (R(y) ⟹ A(y, x))\Big)$$

Your second effort at translating is successful, but be careful with parentheses, which convey the scope of the quantifiers, and bind the variables. Note that:

$$¬∃x∈D, \Big(R(x) ⟹ ¬∃y∈D, (T(y) ∧ A(x, y))\Big)$$ $$ \equiv \forall x \in D \Big(R(x) \implies \exists y \in D (T(y) \land A(x,y))\Big)$$

Comment: Nice write up +1

Comment: $\ddot\smile$ +)

Answer (score 0):

The "flipping" is because your definition requires $x$ to be a programmer, but the statement names the programmer $y$. Also
$$\forall\ y\in D : R(y) \wedge A(y,x)$$
means, all "things" in $D$ are programmers assigned to $x$. You forgot about the ($x$ and other) projects in $D$

---

The (correct) given solution is to be interpreted as:

> There is $x$ in $D$ ($\exists\ x\in D$), such that $x$ is a project ($T(x)$) and for all elements $y$ in $D$ ($\forall\ y\in D$), $y$ being a programmer ($R(y)$) implies ($\Rightarrow$) $y$ is assigned to $x$ ($A(y,x)$).

Your statements says

> These is $x$ in $D$, such that $x$ is a project and all elements $y$ in $D$ are programmers AND they are all assigned to $x$

---

**Regarding the addendum**
This is correct, but a little more straightforward would be
$$\forall x \in D : R(x) \Rightarrow \exists y \in D: T(y) \wedge A(x,y)$$